# Unable to understand an argument in proof of theorem of Hungerford Algebra Ch - Fields and Galois Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, separable-extension

I am self studying Algebra from the book Thomas Hungerford and I am unable to think about an argument on Page -260 of the book.

Adding it's image[image]

> I have a question in 11 th line of proof ie Why "there exists an injective map from $\tau$ into set P "?

Can someone please explain the reason for that?

Comment: Because of the sentence before:" Hence $\phi$ resp.$\psi$ may be identified with its graph."

Comment: @DietrichBurde got it thanks!!